# Field of research treating tetrads (vierbeins) as fundamental objects?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, research-level, qft-in-curved-spacetime

After a lot of research on tetrads I think I found the subject I'd like to specialize in for postgrad/phd, as they seem to express many interesting and (perhaps) fundamental physical properties. So i guess my questions are:

- How do tetrads fit in modern unification theories (string th., supersymmetry, loop q.g. etc)?
- Is there one of them (or another) where they enter as more fundamental objects rather than a tool to deal with spinors?

Any guidance on the subject is welcome, as I have not the tools and knowledge to navigate all the bibliography to form a solid opinion myself. The closest answer I've found so far is [teleparallel gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleparallelism).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you tell us what excites you so much about local coordinate systems and why you think they are still worth research after what, 200 years?

Comment: Everytime I post about it I get flagged for speculation and similars. They seem to incorporate the equivalence principle by letting us erect a LIF in a non coordinate basis (two cornerstones of GR), can be seen as the (abusing the term) "square root" of the metric tensor in the same sense that spinors are wrt vector representations (are more fundamental), generate the correct EMT as a source of the gravitational field via variations (Belinfante) and let us deal with objects that do not have a GCT group representation. It seems clunky, but I wish i could make a post about it

Answer (score -3):

The closest answer I've found so far is TELEPARALLEL GRAVITY, as it tries to formulate General Relativity in terms of tetrad fields rather than the metric tensor itself
Here are two papers on the subject:
[From theory to cosmology](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.13793)
[Is Teleparallel Gravity equivalent to GR](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04569)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Edited by barely repeating what I asked in the second question. Any google search will be more satisfactory than an improvised explanation on my part. With regards to the first question, well, I still don't know

Comment: @modellatore "Any google search will be more satisfactory than an improvised explanation on my part." then this shouldn't be posted as an answer

Comment: I asked whether there was such a theory, not for someone to explain it to me. How is posting it's name with bibliography not an answer?! @NíckolasAlves

Comment: Link-only answers become useless if the link [rots away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), so while this may theoretically answer the question, please include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers are [not considered answers](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/859/168783) here and will be deleted.